# How to deal with different amount of inputs that user will choose in a windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm trying to make a database application with C# and an Excel file. I got three tables '**Person**', '**City**' and '**District**'. Each one is a class and they have 5, 2 and 3 properties respectively.

In Form1, I got a **data grid view** and I want to user to choose which table he/she want to do something(insert, update ect.), but my tables have a different amount of properties, so I need a different amount of textboxes depends on user's choice. (For **City** I need 3; for **Person**, I need 5). Also, I'm making this project by three-layered architecture so I have some constraints to deal with problems.

I've started to do this by user control but I'm really stuck. Can anybody explain widely how to deal with it? Thank you.

Comment: You have a fixed amount of options (3 tables)... so whats the big problem?

Comment: @EpicKip I am simply not sure what to do... I've tried to make 3 different user controls for each set of input. For expample, if user chooses insert to City, city control set will appear. But I don't think this is a handy way. Do you?

Comment: @emremrah In your case it works fine, just 3 user controls you wont need a generic solution. I did it with usercontrols for like 10 tables in 1 program.

Comment: @EpicKip So, can you help to emremrah  , how did you do this

Comment: @EpicKip I understand. Did you created the controls when the user chooses or created them when form is load? I mean, created it first and appear them on user's chooice.

Comment: @emremrah I used something to hold the usercontrol (panel or something) when the user asks to show 1 I clear the panels items/controls and then load in the user control. So I load them on demand. But you could use something like tabpages if you want

Comment: @emremrah No problem, good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use a List of controls for each option. 
When you choose to manage table 1, you clear a panel, and for each needed value you create a new control(text box or combo box or...) and you give each control a location and a size and add it to a List of controls. 
When submitting you loop over the list knowing that list(0) is username for example